# Recover cron jobs through file structure

Tags: centos, cron

One of the drives on my server recently gave out and corrupted the OS. I was able to restore all the files, but now I have a backup drive with just the file system; not bootable. I'm setting up a new server now, and need to setup the old cron jobs. Is there a way to look through the file structure to see all cron jobs that were setup on the old server? Server was CentOS, not sure of version. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crontabs belonging to individual users should be found in

```
/var/spool/cron/##USERNAME##
```

Whereas the server-wide crontab should be in

```
/etc/crontab
```

Comment: On Debian, it's /var/spool/cron/crontabs/USERNAME.